# OpenCL: using struct as kernel argument

Tags: opencl

Can I use struct as OpenCL kernel argument?

I want to use struct type as OpenCL kernel argument in NVIDIA OpenCL 1.2 (NVIDIA driver 352.39)

I tried, but it makes CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCE error.

What is wrong in my code??

[for struct definition]

```
/* struct type definition */
typedef struct _st_foo
{
    int aaa;
    int bbb;
     .....
    int zzz;
}st_foo;      // st_foo doesn't have any pointer members
```

[Host code]

```
/* OpenCL initalize... */

st_foo stVar;

cl_mem cm_buffer;
cm_buffer = clCreateBuffer(cxContext, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(st_foo), NULL, NULL);
clSetKernelArg(ckKernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&cm_buffer);
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cqueue, cm_buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(st_foo), &stVar, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

[Kernel code]

```
__kernel void testfunction(__global const st_foo *stVar)
{
    printf("stVar->aaa=%d\n", stVar->aaa);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not safe to declare structs in OpenCL if you are not using the OpenCL datatypes. And also, alignment may be an issue, force a packet alignment in the Host/Device compiler.

You should declare your structs as:

[Host]

```
typedef struct __attribute__ ((packed)) _st_foo
{
    cl_int aaa;
    cl_int bbb;
     .....
    cl_int zzz;
}st_foo;
```

[Device]

```
typedef struct __attribute__ ((packed)) _st_foo
{
    int aaa;
    int bbb;
     .....
    int zzz;
};
```

Aditionally, if you just want a single parameter, not an array of structs, then just pass it in as:

```
clSetKernelArg(ckKernel, 0, sizeof(mystruct), mystruct);
```

Comment: I tried to pass in a struct as a non-pointer value and I couldn't build the kernel.

Are you certain static objects are allowed as kernel arguments?

Comment: Kernel arguments that are not buffers (ie: non-pointers, ints, structs, etc...), can be passed as arguments directly. As long as you have enough constant memory available in the device to keep that structure.

Comment: This now appears to break my struct allignment rather than fix it for me using Clang on Windows and openCL C++ 3.x (NVIDIA driver 517.40). The struct data is read in the kernel correctly only if I use a straight `struct Foo { ... };` definition on both host and device (using `cl_xxxx` types on the host side).

Is this `__attribute__ ((packed))` no longer needed? And am I likely to run into portablility issues if I stick with the straight struct definitons? (I haven't got another environemtn to tet on currently)